AG Grid 22.1.1: Select all in Column list panel doesn't update hidden column
I want to make the "Select All" checkbox(checkbox besides search box) select/deselect all column checkboxes in the ag-Grid column visibility tool panel. However, I noticed that the "Select All" functionality does not work on columns that have hide: true in their column definitions (colDef).
In the example below, the "Owner" column has hide: true (see colDef in the code snippet), and clicking "Select All" has no effect on this column.
    const columnDefs = [
{
    field: 'transactionId',
    width: 160,
    filter: GRID_REGISTERED_FILTER_NAMES.CGridConditonalFilter,
    hide: false,
    enableRowGroup: true,
},
{
    field: 'assetName',
    width: 150,
    enableRowGroup: true,
    hide: false,
    resizable: true,
},
{
    field: 'amount',
    width: 150,
    enableRowGroup: true,
    hide: false,
    resizable: true,
},
{
    field: 'exitValue',
    width: 150,
    hide: false,
    filter: GRID_REGISTERED_FILTER_NAMES.CGridNumberFilter,
    enableRowGroup: true,
},
{
    field: 'owner',
    width: 150,
    hide: true,
    filter: GRID_REGISTERED_FILTER_NAMES.CGridListFilter,
    filterParams: {
        filterId: 'owner',
        filterLabel: 'Owner',
        initialFilterData: [],
        showTooltip: true,
        valueSelectorKey: 'id',
        dataProvider: optionsDataProvider,
    },
    enableRowGroup: true,
    resizable: true,
},
{
    field: 'transactionDate',
    width: 150,
    hide: false,
    enableRowGroup: true,
    resizable: true,
},

];
In the below example Owner has hide as true(see coldef in code snippet) and clicking on select all has not effect.
But in my case I want to keep some columns as hidden in the beginning. And allow user to select all the columns when clicked on select all.
I checked the ag-grid code(see code snippet) and find out that hidden columns are filter out. Is there any way to achieve the same.
    public updateSelections(): void {
    if (this.columnApi.isPivotMode()) {
        // if pivot mode is on, then selecting columns has special meaning (eg group, aggregate, pivot etc),
        // so there is no bulk operation we can do.
        _.iterateObject(this.columnComps, (key, column) => {
            column.onSelectAllChanged(this.selectAllChecked);
        });
    } else {
        // however if pivot mode is off, then it's all about column visibility so we can do a bulk
        // operation directly with the column controller. we could column.onSelectAllChanged(checked)
        // as above, however this would work on each column independently and take longer.
        if (!_.exists(this.filterText)) {
            const primaryCols = this.columnApi.getPrimaryColumns();
            // we don't want to change visibility on lock visible / hidden columns
            const colsToChange = primaryCols.filter(col => {
                return !col.getColDef().lockVisible && !col.getColDef().hide;
            });
            this.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(colsToChange, this.selectAllChecked);
            return;
        }

        // obtain list of columns currently filtered
        const filteredCols: string[] = [];
        _.iterateObject(this.filterResults, (key, passesFilter) => {
            if (passesFilter) filteredCols.push(key);
        });

        if (filteredCols.length > 0) {
            // update visibility of columns currently filtered
            this.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(filteredCols, this.selectAllChecked);

            // update select all header with new state
            const selectionState = this.selectAllChecked ? SELECTED_STATE.CHECKED : SELECTED_STATE.UNCHECKED;
            this.dispatchEvent({type: 'selectionChanged', state: selectionState});
        }
    }
}


